# Modifying SQL Results from Select Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to take the results of the below query and perform an Update to NAME_UD_AFFILIATIONS and Set the Member_Status field to N.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Ver. 9.0 on Windows 7

```
SELECT *
FROM NAME
INNER JOIN Name_UD_Affiliations ON NAME.ID=Name_UD_Affiliations.ID
WHERE 
NAME_UD_AFFILIATIONS.Member_Status='R' and 
Name.Join_Date > '2012-9-1' and 
Name.Paid_Thru > '2013-09-01'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using SQL-Server you can do

```
UPDATE Name_UD_Affiliations 
SET Member_Status = 'N'
FROM NAME
 INNER JOIN Name_UD_Affiliations ON NAME.ID=Name_UD_Affiliations.ID
WHERE NAME_UD_AFFILIATIONS.Member_Status='R'
AND Name.Join_Date > '2012-9-1'
AND Name.Paid_Thru > '2013-09-01'
```